# How to use ClientRpc (or ServerRpc) in unity Netcode for GameObject?

Tags: unity-game-engine, networking

I'm having trouble understanding how to use those Rpc's correctly. Sometimes they work sometimes they don't.
Example : I have this gameobject that is in the scene (not instantiated on connection), called "Book", it has a script ("SpellManager") so when both player connect, they both have this object in their scene.
Now in that SpellManager script, I want my Host/Server to change a spell variable on collision. Let's say I have a "string newSpell" variable, how do I change this variable on the server side and then send the information to the clients ? I have tried something like this (simplified) :

```
    private string newSpell;

    private void OnTriggerEnter(Collider other)
    {
        if (NetworkManager.Singleton.IsServer)
        {
            newSpell = "Earth";
            testClientRpc(Time.frameCount, newSpell);
        }
        else
        {
            print("OnClient ");
        }
    }
    [ClientRpc]
    public void testClientRpc(int somenumber, string _newSpell)
    {
        newSpell = _newSpell;
    }
```

But this trows an error on the server : `NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object Unity.Netcode.NetworkBehaviour.get_NetworkManager () (at Library/PackageCache/com.unity.netcode.gameobjects@1.0.0-pre.4/Runtime/Core/NetworkBehaviour.cs:219)`
And it's coming from the `_newSpell` variable which is apparently null ? I even tried hardcoding newspell = "Earth" in the ClientRpc, same error. An example/video would be much appreciated, I couldn't find anything similar

Answer (score 2):

1. The Object which has a Script deriving from the `NetworkBehaviour` (because you are using `RPC`) must have a `NetworkObject` component attached to it.
2. If you are calling the `RPC` from a **Non-Owner** object, you must set the `requireOwnership` option to false in the attribute options i.e. `[ServerRpc(requireOwnership = false)]`